# created and inserted table in RDS in python, it shows no error but I am not able see it in AWS RDS

Tags: python, mysql, rds

created and inserted table in aws rds in python .it is showing output also but it is not reflecting in RDS.

```
import mysql.connector

myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host="testdb.cujdryz5rc3f.us- east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", port=3306, user="ninky", password="ninkyrds",  database="Emp_info")

cur = myconn.cursor()
query = """insert into EMP_DETAIL(name,age,salary) values (%s,%s,%s)"""
value = [("deepak", 29, 6700)]
cur.executemany(query, value)
query2="select * from EMP_DETAIL"
cur.execute(query2)
for x in cur.fetchall():
   print(x)
myconn.close()

output
--------
('deepak', 29, 6700)
```

shall be greatful if anyone helps in this.

Comment: I am not sure, Try `myconn.commit()`

Comment: tried it before but there is no change.

Comment: How did you connect to RDS? Can you specify the command?